# Custom template tags

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

I have a model name "Attendee". In that there are foreignkeys as user and model named "Event".

Now I have to get the users of Attendee who are going for event.

```
{% get_event_attendee event as attending_event %}
```

it works for me. But I need this step with "for",
    I mean

```
{% get_event_attendee for event as attending_event %}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1919/

Previous I had a damn thing to do.  Go through with that you will definitely crack that :)

Answer (score 1):

If your models look like this

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    ...


class Event(models.Model):
    ...


class Attendee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

you can access the attendees in the template like this:

```
{% for attendee in event.attendee_set.all %}
    {{ attendee.user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is this your question?

If you have multiple events you can use two forloops:

```
{% for event in event_list %}
    {% for attendee in event.attendee_set.all %}
        {{ attendee.user }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was asked with the format of {% template_tag for users as user_object %}. Anyways helped for me. Thanks :)